# How do I show $\arctan x$ is real analytic on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, taylor-expansion, analyticity, elementary-functions

> How do I show $\arctan x$ is real analytic on $\mathbb{R}$?

First of all we have
$$
\arctan x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \, \forall\, x\in[-1,1]
$$
because
$$
\arctan x = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t^2}
=
\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} +(-1)^{m}\int_0^x\frac{t^{2m}}{1+t^2}\,dt
$$
where for all $x\in[-1,1]$
$$
\int_0^x\frac{t^{2m}}{1+t^2}\,dt 
\le
\int_0^x{t^{2m}}\,dt =\frac{|x|^{2m+1}}{2m+1}\to 0 \,(n\to\infty) 
$$

Then to prove that $\arctan x$ is real analytic on $\mathbb{R}$ we certainly should consider the Taylor expansion at other points because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ doesn't converge when $|x|>1$.

**My attempt**

I wanted to avoid evaluating $\arctan^{(n)} a$ but work it out via using the property of power series.

Because we have
$$
\arctan x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \, \forall\, x\in[-1,1]
$$
and
$$ \mathrm{arctanh}\, x 
=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
 \, \forall\, x\in(-1,1)$$
thus $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ is absolutely convegent for $x\in(-1,1)$. We can rearrange it as 
$$
\arctan x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n  \,\, \forall\, x\in(-1,1)
$$
where $$a_n=\frac{\arctan^{(n)} x_0}{n!}$$

Denote $M=\max\{|-1-x_0|,|1-x_0|\}$.

Thus we have
$$
\arctan (x+x_0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \,\, \forall\, x\in(-1-x_0,1-x_0)
$$
which leads to 
$$
\arctan (x+x_0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \,\, \forall\, x\in(-M,M)
$$
And this implies that $\arctan x$ is real analytic.

Does there exist any problems in my poof? And any new ideas would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof doesn't hold. What is $x_0$? Besides, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ only converges on $(-1,1)$.

You can prove that $\arctan$ is analytic observing that $\arctan'x=\dfrac1{1+x^2}$ which is analytic, since it is the quotient of two analytic functions. And a primtive of an analytic function is always analytic.

Comment: Just set $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ for instance. Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ is absolutely convergent on $(-1,1)$, there is a rearrangement of it as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-\frac{1}{2})^n$. Consider it as a new power series and use the property of radius of convergence I tried to expand its domain of convergence. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, I found that it isn't a rearrangement... Thanks for your words.